# What Text Selection Control is this?

Tags: android, textselection

I want to implement the same nature type of control on text selection on a Activity with various text fields. Any ideas of implementing the behavior shown in Picture

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Refer this from the [Android 2.3](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.html) Documentation:

[image]

You can create your own Text Selection Control using this methods.