# Select text from TextView?

Tags: android

Is it possible to select text from a TextView(including highlight) ?

It is possible with EditText but i need that to be done using TextView ..

Any help regarding this please ?

Thanks,

Comment: please elaborate ur question or display any screenshot

Comment: Check this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874266/what-text-selection-control-is-this/4874566#4874566

Comment: @User333 I want to select text(example: A word) from bulk of text present in the textview..

Comment: @vikas TextSelection is introduced in Android 2.3 ,but what if i want to use it for the older versions ?

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989545/make-edittext-behave-as-a-textview-in-code) from the same user

Comment: @dave.c, they're not duplicates.  That question is about how to get a very specific control (and it's only available in 2.3).  This is a more general question about how to get text selection in a TextView.  An answer to that question isn't an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are going for, and this may not be exactly what you want, but you can register it for a ContextMenu and then use `onCreateContextMenu` and the `CLIPBOARD_SERVICE`:

```
private TextView mTextView;

protected final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
registerForContextMenu(mTextView);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view;
        menu.setHeaderTitle(textView.getText()).add(0, 0, 0, R.string.menu_copy_to_clipboard);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ((ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE)).setText(mTextView.getText());
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Use this:

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

as easy as pie ;)

**Edit**:

setting it in code: `textView.setTextIsSelectable(true)`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you do not have to develop this feature by yourself. You just need to use EditText instead TextView, while you set the android:editable of EditText to false.

My answer is here, hope it may help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11026292/966405