# How i can create text selection in listview item?

Tags: java, android, listview, selection

I want to create a text selection in TextView,whitch is located in ListView item. The `copyText.setTextIsSelectable(true);` and `android:textIsSelectable="true"` is not working. The custom action mode not working too.
In LogCat I got a:

> W/TextView﹕ TextView does not support text selection. Action mode cancelled.

I want to create text selection like on this picture:
[image]

Comment: You could try to implement yourself on long press http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386084/how-do-i-enable-standard-copy-paste-for-a-textview-in-android

Comment: @Sharj I understand what you mean,but you misunderstood my problem,I want to create a text selection markers.

Comment: Check the post below :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991201/select-text-from-textview

Comment: @sushantkunal thanks,but I need to show markers to select a text and save in to clipboard like a on image in question.

Comment: @Yuriy Could you please talk about your solution?

Comment: @Yuriy, Can you post your answer. It will help others as well!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a workaround to this problem by popping up an Alert Dialog with the contents of the ListView row on longClick.
The alertdialog has a textview with

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

The user now can select/copy the text he wants from this dialog.

Codewise, something like this:

```
lvMsg.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int pos, long id) {

      final SMessage sms = (SMessage)lvMsg.getItemAtPosition(pos);

       final LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
       View mView = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.copy_text_dialog, null);
       AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilderCopy = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
       alertDialogBuilderCopy.setView(mView);
       TextView copyTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.copyTextView);
       copyTextView.setText(sms.getContent());
       AlertDialog alertDialogAndroidCopy = alertDialogBuilderCopy.create();
       alertDialogAndroidCopy.show();

      }

}
```

Contents of copy_text_dialog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="Long Press to Select Text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/copyTextTitle"></TextView>

    <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="No Text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/copyTextView"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```